# Як перекласти словосполучення "Пользоваться дурной славой"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

"Пользоваться дурной славой" означає бути непопулярним. Цікавить чи є якийсь український відповідник, який б можна було використати для перекладу.

Пошуки в "[Російсько-українському словнику сталих виразів](https://r2u.org.ua/data/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B2%20%281959%29.pdf)" та [словнику Савченко](http://univer.nuczu.edu.ua/tmp_metod/1047/%D1%E0%E2%F7%E5%ED%EA%EE%20%CB.%20%C3._%D0%EE%F1%B3%E9%F1%FC%EA%EE-%F3%EA%F0%E0%BF%ED%F1%FC%EA%E8%E9%20%F1%EB%EE%E2%ED%E8%EA%20%F1%EB%EE%E2%EE%F1%EF%EE%EB%F3%F7%E5%ED%FC.%20%D2%F0%F3%E4%ED%EE%F9%B3%20%EF%E5%F0%E5%EA%EB%E0%E4%F3.pdf) не дали ніяких результатів. І чи буде прийнятний дослівний переклад "користуватися дурною славою" в разі відсутності українського відповідника?

Comment: На мій погляд найкраще підходить "Сумнозвісний" або "мати погану/дурну вдачу"

Comment: @AlexSodin, не варто писати (псевдо-/напів-)відповіді у коментарях. Коментарі під запитанням призначені **винятково** для уточнення/покращення запитання.

Comment: Ьак на мене сье не зовьім _бути непопульарним_, навпаки — _бути попульарним, але з неґативним відтьінком_.

Answer (score 10):

Правильно — [**у неславі бути**](http://wiki.kubg.edu.ua/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0).

- *Погубиш їх, і їх слава стане їм в неславу.* «Давидові псалми» Т. Г. Шевченко.
- *Ой він її не займає, бо сватати має, він до неї не горнеться, неслави боїться.* КС. 1887. VIII. 774.

Answer (score 9):

Здається, вдалося знайти відповідь на це запитання. Натрапив на Словопедії на сторінку із «Як ми говоримо» Антоненка-Давидовича, де є вислів "пользоваться дурной репутацией" (а враховуючи, що "дурная слава" і "дурная репутация" [синоніми](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83/%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), то гадаю, що і ці два фразеологізма також є синонімами):

> Такому російському вислову, як пользоваться дурной репутацией,
>   відповідають українські: **недобру славу мати**, **в неславі бути**;

Знайшов я "пользоваться дурной репутацией" і в [російсько-українському словнику](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/everyfile2.php?transfer=folders/pe/polmzovatmsw.html) сталих виразів, де крім поданих вище варіантів ще зустрічається звичайне "**мати погану репутацію**".